# Is it possible to pass props to "css" element of styled components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I can do this with a styled.div

```
styled.div`
    color: ${props=> props.color || 'black'};
`
```

How can I do something similar with a styled components css element?

```
const BlackBGCSS = css`
    color: ${props=> props.color || 'black'};
`
```

For now my solution is to create a factory function

```
const BlackBGCSS = (props)=> css`
    color: ${props=> props.color || 'black'};
`
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kind of how you have it:

```
const myCSS = css`
    background: ${({ myColor }) => myColor || `black`};
`;

const MyComponent = styled('div')`
    ${myCSS};
`;
```

Then

```
<MyComponent myColor="red">Hello World</MyComponent>
```

Hope that helps.